# react-router-dom, is there a `getComponent` method for code splitting?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-router-v4, webpack-2

I try to figure out how code splitting work with `webpack2.x` and `react-router-dom`.

`"react-router-dom": "^4.0.0"`

But I read the doc and did not find a way to use like this:

`getComponent` still work or not?

I find the `react-router-dom` doc just give you some example, no explain.

I saw `react-router` is `v4.0.0-beta.8`, Maybe I should use `react-router-dom` later?

```
module.exports = {
    path: 'home',
    getComponent(nextState, cb) {
        import('./main').then(component => {
            cb(null, component);
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log('Failed to load "home" component', err);
        });
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `.getComponent()` is no longer available. I think react-router hands off this responsibility to the developer to create his own async components. There is a great guide in the react-router-dom docs about handling code splitting using webpack2 and bundle-loader:
https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/guides/code-splitting.md

And here is awesome quick code splitting example with React Router v4:
https://gist.github.com/acdlite/a68433004f9d6b4cbc83b5cc3990c194

Hope that helps!

Comment: i used to async inject the reducers into the store from withing the getComponent call during async route loading. In those examples there's nothing showing where to do that now. Do you have an idea from where it should be injected now?